# JS Reduce: sum specific position in a nested array of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I want to reduce only a specific position in a nested number array

```
const array1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[11,12,13]];

console.log(array1.reduce((prev, curr) => prev[2] + curr[2]));
```

The result is NaN, another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** You should use `prev` not `prev[2]` as

`prev` is of type `number` that you are returning not an `array`

**2)** If you are adding the number then it is better to take initial value as `0` as a second argument to the `reduce` method.

If you won't pass `second` argument, then `reduce` will take the array element at `0` index as the starting value i.e `[1, 2, 3]` and then if you add `[1, 2, 3] + curr[2]` then it will produce value as `1,2,36`, which you are not expecting

```js
const array1 = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
  [11, 12, 13],
];

console.log(array1.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr[2], 0));
```